# List attachments of a page

Tags: attachments, archives

I need to generate a list of attachments uploaded to a specific page (id=628). I thought this code was going to work, but it doesn't generate anything at all:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
            $attachments =& get_children( array (
                'post_parent' => 628,
                'post_type' => 'attachment'
            ));

            if ( empty($attachments) ) {
                // no attachments here
            } else {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
                    echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id );
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: Remove the `&` from this line `$attachments =& get_children(`. This seems like depreciated syntax or even invalid syntax. Also do a `var_dump()` on `$attachments` and see what is returned

Comment: Ok, I removed the `&` and did a `var_dump($attachments)`. It returned an empty array (I think): `array(0) { }`.

Comment: Jip, you are getting an empty array. According to the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children), your usage is correct (although the syntax is really old and not in use anymore). There is not much you can do to debug this. I would however test this this afternoon. Seems strange that your code is not working. Are you sure your id is correct

Comment: I tested with myurl/?p=628 and it redirects to the page, so I'm sure. The page has a lot of documents attached, mainly PDFs.

Comment: Are you sure the pdf's are actually saved as attachments. Have you checked the `wp_posts` table to make sure about this

Comment: Hm. Not quite sure how I can see assigned attachments in the db. When opening the 628-post entry I see alot of info about the post, but nothing related to any attachments.

Comment: Ahh. I think you're right. My client is doing the uploading, and it seems like perhaps she's using the Media Library to upload the files, because noen of the files are displayed as being attached to any post... I'll sort it out and do a new test.

Comment: No problem. I hope you get this sorted :-)

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. What's the proper thing to do now – should I answer my own question with the solution, even though the solution turned out not to be related to the code? Sorry, I'm rather new to StackExchange.

Comment: If you can manage a proper answer, yes. Remember to accept it as well after the retriction is lifted. Feel free to visit [help] and take a [tour] to help you understand how the SE network works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the files wasn't attached to the post. To make it work I re-attached the files (Media Library > Attach). I also removed the `&` in `$attachments =& get_children( array (`.